# Remove or hide the BIG PLAY BUTTON from the mediaelement.js vdeo coding

Tags: mediaelement.js

Is it possible to remove or hide the big play button from the [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)'s video player code?

Answer (score 7):

You can update your site's css to include 
`.mejs-overlay-button {display:none;}`

The mediaelementplayer.css file is fairly self explanatory and allows you to tweak the entire player design.

Comment: For me, the name of the class was actually .mejs__overlay-button